# IIS 7 identify virtual directory from metabase path

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, metabase

I am trying to profile the number of "Anonymous Requests" for an ASP.NET web application using perfmon.  When I select this key, I have to pick a process of the form _LM_W3SVC_#_ROOT.  How do I map the IIS metabase path back to the web application?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the advanced settings for the site to get the AppId.  If AppId is 3 then metabase key is _LM_W3SVC_3_ROOT.